# How to match every beginning of new line of text in Regex?

Tags: regex, csv

I'm in the process of creating a CSV file out of a text file. Very new to Regex and I need to finish the CSV file.

What I need to do is to remove every new line of text and put them in one single line.

For example, this data:

```
ABC Company INC
123 Some Street 
Winchester, KY
```

Needed to be in this format:

```
ABC Company INC;123 Some Street;Winchester, KY
```

**Plus**, on my file... it has several entries with one line-break every after one company.

It's like this:

```
ABC Company
123 Street
Winchester, KY

DEF Company
456 Street
Winchester, KY
```

And make it like so:

```
ABC Company;123 Street;Winchester, KY
DEF Company;456 Street;Winchester, KY
```

Can we do that in Regex? If so, then how?

**More Info:**

This is not for programming or coding related issue.

It's more of data conversion or manipulation. I'm only using a text editor. I need to edit the text file (mined data) and convert it to a CSV file.

If there are other tools that we might use for this, then please mention about it.

**UPDATE:**

With this particular problem at hand, with my current level of knowledge, I found the answer of **Bohemian** more helpful in my case. It did help me well with the task.

However, the answer provided by **Sobrique** is more powerful to use. Only I don't know how to use it well. What I did with the Pearl script is... I copied the whole printed output of the script since I don't know how to output it to a file. Plus, I also encountered some inaccurate data. It's a great tool, only I couldn't handle it right now.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: No need for regex to do this, just use your language's string manipulation tools.

Comment: Could you just use a programming language like Python, Ruby, C, whatever instead of regular expressions?

Comment: Added new info above.

Comment: If it isn't a programming and coding related issue, then it's off topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a replace like this:

```
 Search: (?<=.)$(\s(?!^$))+^
Replace: ;
```

then, to remove the blank lines:

```
 Search: ^$\s+
Replace: <nothing>
```

Those look arounds are there to make sure that blank lines (of zero length) are not matched.

Comment: It works, but how should I use it with multiple data. I've updated my question above. I'm using Sublime Text to make the edits.

Comment: @Kupalzky I've edited the answer and tested it using TextWranger. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Will try with Sublime Text

Comment: @Kupalzky A great reference site to help learn is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). There are numerous on-line sites to try regex - my favourite is [Rubular](http://rubular.com). And there is the [stackoverflow regex reference page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/256196), which has links to lots of other instructive questions/answers.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions aren't really the tool for this job. They're about pattern matching.

You might find that `tr` is suitable, as you can transliterate `linefeed` to `;`.

Alternatively in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print;
    if (m/^\s*$/) {
        print "\n";
    }
    else {
        print ";";
    }
}

__DATA__
ABC Company
123 Street
Winchester, KY

DEF Company
456 Street
Winchester, KY
```

Will do the trick.

To turn this into a one liner:

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { chomp; print; if (m/^\s*$/) { print "\n" } else { print ";" } }' yourfile
```

(`perl -i` enables 'inplace editing' - this will just print it)

Comment: I tried this, but I does not make any changes. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, Perl v5.18.2

Comment: It won't work in light of the changes you made. I shall edit. It doesn't edit the file - if it works, you'll need to redirect the output to a file

Comment: It works using the one liner, but couldn't figure how to output to file. Tried `mysource-file output-file`

Comment: Something like: > outputfile